# WPF Как создать один ресурс строку через другой ресурс строку?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть директория с изображениями, которую я в будущем скорее всего перемещу. Поэтому мне бы хотелось создать строку, в которой записан в путь к нынешнему её расположению, а доставать из неё изображения будут уже ресурсы используя созданную мной строку. Я хотел реализовать это так, но не получилось.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="imagesDirectory">d:\Images</sys:String>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="backgroundBrush" ImageSource="{StaticResource imagesDirectory}\HelloWindowBackGroundImage.jpg" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Если есть возможность по другому реализовать то, что я хочу, то подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Этого вообще в коде не должно быть. Пользователь не должен думать о том, где у него картинка... Разместите в корне проекта и относительно этой директории берите путь. Можете создать файл настроек и вынести подобное туда.

Comment: Вы же не хотите пересобирать приложение каждый раз при изменении пути? Положите этот путь в файл настроек например, который может лежать в папке приложения.